How to get the count of addresses that appear once and multiple times in google looker studio
i added fields for count(street) and 'kemunculan' means appearence contains rows of data 'once' for count(street)=1 else 'several times'. It went well when i put the data into a table, but what i really need is the count of addresses appeared once and several times in to socore cards. but it got "NO DATA".

i tried to do what chat gpt told me to do such as :

Scorecard 1: Count of Addresses Appearing Once Add a Scorecard to your
report. In the Metric section, select COUNT_DISTINCT(Street) (or
whatever field represents the distinct addresses). Add a Filter to
only include addresses that appear once: Click Add a Filter. Set the
filter condition to: Include: Address Count equals 1. This will show
the total count of distinct addresses that appear once.

i did all the inctructions but still got NO DATA instead.

